# Ring of processes with 2 one-way pipes?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, process

I wrote a program where we had a Ring of n processes with one-way pipes. Now I had a question where I need to implement the same program using 2 one-way pipes, is it possible ?

Its something like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/TAgL0kr]

For example, Process 0 sends a message to be received by Process 1, and so on, to back to Process 0 and done. Whenever a process sends or receives a message, it prints its process # (N), "the message", and "sent" or "received".

I have this working with one-way pipe but couldn't figure out how to get it done by using 2 pipe.

Any help, hint would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But there's only one standard input and one standard output, so you'll need to come up with your own numbering convention for the additional input and output FDs.

Comment: Call `pipe()` twice for each process. Hook up the first pipe the way you already are, connect the second pipe to the FDs for the reverse direction.

Comment: Can't really provide much more than hints like that. If you want detailed assistance, show the code you tried to write for it and we'll explain where you went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about it so haven't tried anything.

Will try your suggestion and post back.